# Multiple condition for SQLITE Triggers

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to update a field on a different table if the current table that is declared on the trigger gets updated. But I need to update only after 2 conditions

```
    public class Match{
        public int participant1;
        public int participant2;
        public int winner;
        public boolean finalMatch;
        public int standingId;
    }

        public class Standings{
            public int id;
            public int firstPlace;
            public int SecondPlace;
        }

private static final String CREATE_TRIGGER_MATCH_UPDATE_BRACKET_WINNERS_F1 = "CREATE TRIGGER if not exists updatefields
        AFTER UPDATE OF  winner
            ON Match
            WHEN new.finalMatch = 1 AND new.winner = new.participant1
            BEGIN
            UPDATE Standings
                SET firstPlace = new.winner
                    SecondPlace = new.participant2
            WHERE id = new.standingId
        END;"
```

But this throws an error. Apparently there can only be on "WHEN condition" for triggers on android. Now I'm not really sure how to go about checking it. As I would like to do this update of the two fields on one trigger. If I do two triggers, 1 for the setting up of "firstPlace" and another for the "secondPlace", the second one will be on the Standings table and I'm not really sure how to get access to that "secondPlace" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the syntax ([trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), [update](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)) errors, the trigger is accepted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER if not exists updatefields
AFTER UPDATE OF winner ON Match
WHEN new.finalMatch = 1 AND new.winner = new.participant1
BEGIN
    UPDATE Standings
    SET firstPlace  = new.winner,          -- comma here
        SecondPlace = new.participant2
    WHERE id = new.standingId;             -- semicolon here
END;
```